# What can I do about a toilet flange that is 1/4" below the floor

Tags: plumbing

My toilet leaks after i flush and doesn't seal properly at all…tried different kind of wax rings and aaah .. no solution ..cause leak and damage to downstairs ceiling ..better said it leaks and the elbow joint , if that helps

Comment: Perhaps a picture would help.

Comment: How many holes for toilet bolts does your toilet have? I've seen some with 4, and you can offset it in the wrong place: half off the pipe where it should be.

Answer (score 2):

I have used rise-a-ring in the past a plastic spacer that brings the flange up to the new floor level after adding tile.

Answer (score 1):

A toilet flange 1/4" below the finished floor is very common and will seal with a standard wax ring.

- You either aren't installing it correctly (call a reliable plumber, stat.)

or

- You have a problem unrelated to the wax ring (call a reliable plumber, stat.)

Answer (score 0):

At most plumbing suppliers you can now buy brass or plastic rings that screw directly onto the existing ring to gain height. Even cheaper and possibly as effective in your case is a thicker wax ring **Oatey** makes a double thickness wax ring with a plastic funnel to fit in the drain.